# Scada-LTS DataSources Testing application

Tags: scada

I'm looking for some SCADA DataSources testing applications like this one "http://modbuspal.sourceforge.net/" but especially application including every source type. Is something like that existing or better should I write in on my own?

Comment: A great idea for a dedicated tool.

Comment: You can try http://hercules-setup.soft32.com/